# Python serial checks refactoring

Tags: python

Ho can this code be optimized?
Maybe it is possible to write it shorter, make it more 'pythonic'?

```
...
check_pass = 0

if key == 'media':
    size_check_pass = 0
    if some_check_func(xxx): size_check_pass = 1
    ...

    format_checks_pass = 0
    if...some_checks... : format_checks_pass = 1

    if size_check_pass and format_checks_pass: check_pass = 1

if key == 'text':
    line_end_check_pass = 0
    if (((some checks))): line_end_check_pass = 1

    lenght_check_pass = 0
    if len(file) < 1000: lenght_check_pass = 1

    if line_end_check and lenght_check_pass: check_pass = 1

if check_pass:
    ...
```

The background of the code is to check each file type for different conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary as a sort of dispatch table perhaps. Something like

```
def media_checks(f): 
  ...
  return pass

def text_checks(f): 
  ...
  return pass

_dispatch = {}
_dispatch['media'] = media_checks
_dispatch['text'] = text_checks

dispatch_func = _dispatch[key]
check_pass = dispatch_func(your_file)
```

This would split you code up so it is easier to read and maintain. It also isolates the code for checking each file type in an individual function.

Answer (score 0):

First, for your first `if`, your code suffers from conditional complexity code smell. You can fix with `inline method` refactoring: you don't need your `size_check_pass` and `format_checks_pass` booleans, and can evaluate both conditions directly in the final if statement, with `if ...some_checks... and some_check_func(xxx)` instead of `if size_check_pass and format_checks_pass`. which gives you

```
check_pass = 0

if key == 'media':

    if ...some_checks... and some_check_func(xxx): 
         check_pass = 1
```

Then, do this for the second `if` also. And you don't want to check if `key = 'text'` if you had already that `key = 'media'`, so in the end

```
check_pass = 0

if key == 'media':
    if some_check_func(xxx)and ...some_checks...: 
         check_pass = 1

else if key == 'text':
    if (((some checks)))and len(file) < 1000: 
         check_pass = 1

if check_pass:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So you always have a sequence of checks.

First, you can shorten your conditions:

```
...
check_pass = False # to make it more boolean

if key == 'media':
    size_check_pass = some_check_func(xxx)
    format_checks_pass = ...result of your checks...
    check_pass = size_check_pass and format_checks_pass

if key == 'text':
    line_end_check_pass = (((some checks)))

    length_check_pass = len(file) < 1000

    check_pass = line_end_check and length_check_pass

if check_pass:
    ...
```

or compress them even more:

```
...
check_pass = False # to make it more boolean

if key == 'media':
    check_pass = some_check_func(xxx) and ...result of your checks...

if key == 'text':
    check_pass = (((some checks))) and len(file) < 1000

if check_pass:
    ...
```

And then you could apply a system like the one from jamesj, but maybe with lists of conditional expressions:

```
def some_checks():
  ...
  return True or False

def other_checks(f): 
  ...
  return ...

_dispatch = {
    'media': [lambda: some_check_func(xxx), some_checks],
    'text' : [other_checks, lambda: len(file) < 1000]
}

dispatch_list = _dispatch[key]
check_pass = all(func() for func in dispatch_list)
```